# Angular Date Pipe en-NZ

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using the angular date picker and have set the locale to en-NZ in the app module like so.

```
  {
        provide: LOCALE_ID,
        deps: [LocaleService],      //some service handling global settings
        useFactory: (LocaleService: { locale: string; }) => LocaleService.locale
    },
```

I am using the shortDateFromat but angular date pipe is not formating to the correct locale.

```
Expected: 6/9/21
Actual: 9/6/21
```

It appears that it is always formatting to the en-US locale.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your app.module.ts this:

```
import {  LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
...
@NgModule({
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-nz' }],
})
```

It works for me.